# "Error: Could not find or load main class" in Windows / DOS Compiler

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am new to Java, learning it after programming in C and C++ for a long time.  I am writing on my Windows 7 laptop, using the great guide at docs.oracle.com for my tutorial.  I am working with the Java SE Development Kit 8 (JDK 8) on Windows, and in general, I'm making good progress.

According to this page (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2c), if I want to compile and run a HelloWorld app in the current directory, I use these commands in a DOS window:

```
C:\myapplication>javac HelloWorldApp.java      // to compile
C:\myapplication>java -cp . HelloWorldApp      // to run
```

This worked when I tried it.  But later I expanded HelloWorldApp.java program to include a number of classes.  I decided to create directory called "MyPackage" and move all my code into that directory.  Now I can compile easily enough using this command:

```
C:\myapplication>javac MyPackage\HelloWorldApp.java      // to compile, this works
```

But how to run this program?  I've tried all of the following:

```
C:\myapplication>java -cp .\MyPackage HelloWorldApp      // to run, doesn't work
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp
C:\myapplication>java -cp . MyPackage\HelloWorldApp      // to run, doesn't work
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp
C:\myapplication>java -cp .\MyPackage MyPackage\HelloWorldApp      // to run, doesn't work
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp
C:\myapplication>cd MyPackage
C:\myapplication\MyPackage>java -cp . HelloWorldApp      // to run, doesn't work
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp
```

I've tried additional combos, but can't figure out how to get the program to run.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
            -Pete

Comment: Is your full class name `MyPackage.HelloWorldApp`? Try using that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C:\myapplication>java MyPackage.HelloWorldApp
```

Should do what you want.  -cp stands for classpath, [Reference page here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

The default classpath is `.` so you don't need to explicitly set this.  Then use the fully qualified class name (package name + class name separated by a `.`).

This assumes that you have a `public static void main(String args[])` method (entry point) in the HelloWorldApp class.